# Return how many times each letter of the alphabet appears in a string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, iteration

I wrote a function to count the occurrence of a single letter in a given string:

```
def count_letters(string, letter):
'''returns the number of letters letter in a sentence string.'''

count = 0
for char in string:
    if char == letter:
        count += 1
return count
```

Now, I want to find a way to return, in list format, the number of times ALL letters occur (assuming they're all lowercase - I'm using `string.lower()`). I initialized a letter counter to a list of 26 0's:

```
letter_counter = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

But I am not sure how to traverse a given string and append the list for each individual letter.

Ex. if `string = "Hello"`, `letter_counter` returns:

```
letter_counter = [0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I thought it just be a matter of a for loop within a for loop, but it seems more complex. Or maybe I've just been looking at it for too long.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using `collections.Counter` is the most idiomatic to count occurrences in a sequence. You can also do a for loop over `letter_counter`, making sure to convert each index into a char with `chr(ord('A' + i))`.

Answer (score 1):

Why re-invent the wheel?

You can just use `collections.Counter(string)` which will return a dictionary with all the letters in the string as the keys and the frequency as the value of said key.

Comment: Ah, fair enough, I mostly just wanted to see if it COULD be done with for loops :)

Answer (score 1):

The better way is to use collections as Alessandro Power and Pythonista suggested. If you do not want to use that black box then this is what you can do.

```
    # Replace this with your string
    string = 'AbcdEfghiJ'
    # create dictionary to locate a position of each letter
    str_dict = {'a':0, 'b':1, 'c':2, 'd':3, 'e':4, 'f':5, 'g':6, 'h':7,
        'i':8, 'j':9, 'k':10, 'l':11, 'm':12, 'n':13, 'o':14,
        'p':15, 'q':16, 'r':17, 's':18, 't':19, 'u':20, 'v':21,
        'w':22, 'x':23, 'y':24, 'z':25}
    letter_counter = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
    # locate a position of char in letter_counter and add 1.
    for char in string:
        str_lower = char.lower()
        letter_counter[str_dict[str_lower]] += 1

    print letter_counter
```

Out[1]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you know how I can make this work with sentences? When I try to do a sentence with spaces (ex. "hello goodbye"), it returns Key Error: '  '  I tried to use .strip() and .replace(), but that didn't work.

Comment: @maio123maio: You should add "if char!=' ':  " to make sure to count only letters and not space. Then the code will look something like this:

Comment: .......
for char in string:
    if char!=' ':  # '!=' means 'is not equal to'
        str_lower = char.lower()
        letter_counter[str_dict[str_lower]] += 1
print letter_counter

Answer (score 1):

To count letters, you have many options, in order of preference:

1. `collections.Counter` if you want to get this done quickly.
2. Use a dictionary (which is what `Counter` does)
3. Use a (zero) padded list - your approach.

The collection.Counter approach is very simple:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('hello').most_common()
[('l', 2), ('h', 1), ('e', 1), ('o', 1)]
```

The dictionary approach, requires a bit more work. There are two ways you can do it. The first, is to use the `setdefault` method of dictionaries to make sure that the first time you see a letter, it is initialized properly with a default value.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for letter in 'hello':
...    d[letter] = d.setdefault(letter, 0) + 1
...
>>> d
{'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1}
```

The second approach uses the same concept as above, but uses a `defaultdict` instead:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(int)
>>> for letter in 'hello':
...    d[letter] += 1
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {'h': 1, 'e': 1, 'l': 2, 'o': 1})
```

A defaultdict is an object that takes a callable (a function), the value of which will be assigned as the default if a key doesn't exist in the dictionary. The same as `setdefault` but a bit more flexible in what it can do.

The final option is a zero padded list:

```
>>> counts = [0 for i in range(25)]
>>> for letter in 'hello':
...     counts[ord(letter.lower()) % 97] += 1
...
>>> counts
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> counts[11]
2
```

There are a few issues with this approach; the biggest one is that it only works with certain words, it will not work with phrases such as `hello world` or those words that are concatenations, or with punctuation: `We've won!`

You can always program around these, but the other approaches don't have these problems.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert lowercase chars directly to 0-based indexes by converting them to their unicode index using [`ord()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#ord) and subtracting 97 ('a' = 97, 'b' = 98, etc):

```
def count_letters(word):
    l_count = [0] * 26
    for c in word.lower():
        l_count[ord(c)-97] += 1
    return l_count

> count_letters('aaabbc')
[3, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

You should definitely avoid looping through the string 26 times to count each letter individually!

Answer (score 0):

- This is a simple way to count the frequency of each character in a
  String using **java** programming
- Note : It gives output in alphabetical order, not in order of
  occurrence.
- eg: input: "Hello" output: e= 1 h= 1 l= 2 o= 1

  ```
  class char_frequency
      { public static void main (String s)
  { s=s.toLowerCase();
      for (char i= 'a'; i<='z'; i++)
      {check (s,i);}
  }

  public static void check (String s, char ch)
  { int l= s.length(); char a='a'; int c=0;
      for (int i= 0; i<=l-1; i++)
      { a= s.charAt (i);
          if (ch== a)
              c++;

      }
           if (c>0)
           System.out.println ( ch+ "= " + c);
  }
  ```

  }